# Return multiple data using json in ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

How to return multiple data using jquery, json, ajax and php.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'ajax.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{function:'postAnswer', questionID:$('#questionID').val(), answer:$('#answer').val()},
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        location.reload();
    }
    });
```

Comment: if you are doing `location.reload();` why are you doing ajax????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for json value or it would be variable change like this

```
  data:{function:"postAnswer", questionID:$('#questionID').val(), answer:$('#answer').val()},
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, You need to json encode()  all the data which was returned in ajax.php 
You need to encode it, at that page before return.

```
echo json_encode(data variable name in ajax page);
```

then you need to use this code at the success phase

```
$.ajax({
    url:'ajax.php',
    type:'post',
    data:"passing_dataname"+passing_data,
    success:functiondata, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        var answer=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(answer);

    }
    });
```